# Prove that $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t)$ exists and is finite

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f \colon [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and assume $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(t_n)$ exists and is finite for all strictly increasing sequences $(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq [0,\infty)$ that diverges to $\infty$.

From this I want to prove that $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t)$ exists and is finite. I have tried looking at the definition of $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t)$ existing but with no luck yet. However I do believe that it would be possible to show it from the definition and not use any fancy theorems. The definition I am working with is that $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t)=c$ if
$$
\forall \epsilon>0\exists K \in \mathbb{R}\colon t >K \implies \vert f(t) -c \vert < \epsilon.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(t_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(u_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be two strictly increasing sequences diverging to $\infty$, let $t=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)$ and let $u=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(u_n)$. Can we have $t\ne u$? No, we cannot. To see why, consider the sequence $(v_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ defined as follows:

- $v_1=\min\bigl(\{t_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{u_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\bigr)$;
- $v_2=\min\left(\bigl(\{t_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{u_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\bigr)\setminus\{v_1\}\right)$
- $v_3=\min\left(\bigl(\{t_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{u_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\bigr)\setminus\{v_1,v_2\}\right)$
- $\vdots$

Then $(v_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is strictly increasing and therefore the limit $v=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(v_n)$ exists (in $\Bbb R$). But each $t_n$ is a $v_k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, and therefore $v=t$. By the same argument, $v=u$. So, $t=u$.

So, there is some $l\in\Bbb R$ such that, whenever $(t_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of numbers from $[0,\infty)$ diverging to $\infty$, $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)$. Now, it's not hard to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=l$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $l=\lim f(n)$. Suppose $t_n$ increases to $\infty$ and $f(t_n)$ does not tend to $l$. Then there exists $\epsilon >0$ and a subsequence $(t_{n_k})$ such that $|f(t_{n_k})-l| \geq \epsilon$. Interlace $(1,2,3...)$ and $(t_1,t_2,...)$ to get a sequence $(s_n)$ increasing to $\infty$ such that $\lim f(s_n)$ does not exist. This proves that the limit in the hypothesis does not depend on the particular sequence $(t_n)$. Hence, $\lim_{ t \to \infty} f(t)$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your statement is equivalent if you replace 'stricly increasing' by 'increasing'.

Since you know from José's answer that the limits of $f(t_n)$ have to be equal for all sequences $(t_n)$, it can be easily proved by contradiction. We denote this limit by $c:=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)$. Assume $$\exists \epsilon>0\forall K\in\mathbb R\exists t_K\in\mathbb R_+: t_K>K\land |f(t_K)-c|\geq\epsilon.$$ Now consinder all $K\in\mathbb N$. We know for each $K$ of the existence of $t_K$ with $|f(t_K)-c|\geq\epsilon.$ Then define for $n\in\mathbb N$ the sequence $x_n:=\max\{t_K|K\leq n\}$. This is a increasing sequence diverging to $\infty$. But since $|f(x_n)-c|\geq\epsilon$ the sequence $f(x_n)$ cannot converge to $c$. This is a contradiction.